# Town of Salem: Scrolls

Tags: town-of-salem

Town of Salem is a very good and addicting game but i am worried about the buying the scroll which is supposed to give me a higher change for a certain character. The reason why i'm worried about it is that i don't like these one change pay thing and i don't know if it's permanent if i buy it. Is it permanent or one time use? Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 3):

These scrolls are a one-use items that will disappear as soon as you receive the associated role for a game where you equipped the scrolls.

It will only give you a slightly higher chance in that particular game to get the role associated with the scroll (depending on the number of other players that are using the same scroll), and won't affect any other subsequent games.

From Town of Salem wiki:

> If you receive the role from an equipped scroll, the scroll will vanish. Otherwise, you will keep the scroll.